# Decomposition of non negative Radon measure into $L^1$ and $H^{-1}$ functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

What is a reference for the following result (which appears to be well-known in measure theory)?

> Any non negative Radon measure can be decomposed uniquely into the sum of an absolutely continuous measure and a singular term with respect to the harmonic capacity. The absolute continuous term itself can be decomposed (not uniquely) to a function in $L^1$ and a function in $H^{-1}$ (dual of $H_0^1$).

Comment: Can you point to some work where this result is used? Are the three decomposed parts again non-negative?

Answer (score 2):

You can find both results in Theorems 2.1 and 2.4 in

> Lucio Boccardo, Thierry Gallouët, Luigi Orsina,
>
> Existence and uniqueness of entropy solutions for nonlinear elliptic equations with measure data,
>
> Annales de l'Institut Henri Poincaré C, Analyse non linéaire,
> Volume 13, Issue 5, 1996, https://doi.org/10.1016/S0294-1449(16)30113-5.